# Prevent Chrome Remote Desktop from accepting new connection until current is finished

Tags: remote-desktop, firewall, chrome-remote-desktop

Consider I am using chrome remote desktop to connect to my mac through my ipad; I then use my phone to connect to the same host; the phone gets connected and the connection I had with the ipad drops with no warning. Is it possible to prevent the host from receiving another remote connection until the current one is finished? I am thinking on a scenario where 2 different people will access the same host (not simultaneously). Maybe an easy firewall switch on/off?